# Перенаправление вывода снифера на удаленный хост

Tags: сеть, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переправить вывод снифера (tcpdump или tshark) на удаленный Windows хост. Сервер заряжен под RHEL. SSH соединение. Пока нагуглил только что-то вроде этого.

```
tcpdump -pi br0 -s0 -w - | nc 10.1.1.1 9999
```

Соот. на противоположной стороне надо будет писать аппликацию, которая будет слушать этот сокет, и класть данные в файл.

Может есть способ попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё можно вывод команды отправить по почте (например так)

```
tcpdump -pi br0 -s0 -w - | nc 10.1.1.1 9999 | mail -s "Subject" mail@address.local
```

А на виндовой машине просто забрать его из почты (VBS-скриптов для этого полный инет).

Хотя я бы всё-таки открыл сокет и организовал бы клиент/серверную передачу данных.

Comment: Да, видимо действительно остановлюсь на сокете. Спасибо, вопрос закрыт, я думаю.

Answer (score 0):

На противоположной стороне

```
# nc -l -p 9999 > /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 0):

В одну строку без вмешательства на противоположном хосте, только естественно нужен `user` на `10.1.1.1`

```
tcpdump -pi br0 -s0 -w - | ssh user@10.1.1.1 "cat >> /tmp/file"
```

`ssh` возьмёт свой stdin и передаст `cat`'у, который добавит всё в `/tmp/file`

Comment: Спасибо, это не сработает. На клиенте Win, как я и написал в вопросе. Но натолкнуло на другую мысль. Можно поднять на клиенте TFTP-сервер и закинуть ему этот файл из шелла.

Comment: Не понял про "На клиенте Win". Там что, нет ssh? http://www.openssh.com/windows.htmlне знаю, что приоритетнее простота или безопасность tftp и ssh? Поставить конечно можно. Только для tftpпридётся сформировать файл, мне кажется он не сможет воспринять поток. т.е. далее дамп придётся бить на файлы, как-то отсылать, формировать новые.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант: это с машине на win запустить ssh-client в сторону линуксовой [допустим 10.1.0.2] таким образом:    ssh user@10.1.1.2 "sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -pi br0 -s0 -w - not host 10.1.1.1" > file